# Is there a way to write comments in modern Cobol?

Tags: cobol

I'm trying too see how I could add comments to my COBOL program. I know the modern version of COBOL has a way where comments can be written but I am unsure on how to do this.

Comment: Just a hint Benjer.  The GnuCOBOL SourceForge project space has a Help Getting Started discussion forum to handle this kind of question, and we aren't quite as strict about 'being on point', in Help getting started.

Comment: Good advice from Brian. Get to SourceForge. Get that Programming Guide. @HoboSapiens no, it is not a duplicate. It asks about how to write comments at all, not how to write inline comments, which are only part of the story.

Comment: @HoboSapiens although the possible duplicate does have an answer, amongst the four, that answers this question. Perhaps do the duplicate the other way around and encourage Brian to merge his two answers (this one is more up-to-date, with the ROBODoc reference).

Comment: @HoboSapiens I have flagged the other as duplicate of this :-)

Comment: The duplicate question has four answers, and the answer to this question is not the one which is accepted. Please reopen this question, so the duplicate can be done the other way around, with the more up-to-date answer here augmented with anything missing from the other question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `*>` for inline to-end-of-line comments, fixed and free form (in fixed form the `*>` will have to be in column 7 or greater).
- `*` in column seven for fixed form COBOL
- `*` in column one, extension for free form, *not recommended as it can lead to ambiguous code.*
- and allowed in some `identification division` header paragraphs, `REMARKS` for instance, now marked obsolete, but still used.

Smart COBOL comments are now supported in ROBODoc, latest version enhanced for COBOL.

Comment: So... if you were to merge into this your answer on the other post....

Comment: Bill; I tried typing `MERGE posts ON ASCENDING KEY post-id WITH DUPLICATES IN ORDER COLLATING SEQUENCE IS user-alphabet USING post-1 post-2 GIVING post-3` and it didn't take.   ;-)

Comment: Less clowning around this time @BillWoodger, is there any special sequencing on StackOverflow for that, or is it simply a cut'n'paste operation?

Comment: For us mortals, cut'n'paste only. Sorry for the jargon use of merge. It may be an idea to wait. This question now has three close votes for duplicate. If it gets closed as a duplicate, it would be "best" (as in not the best outcome) to update that one answer amongst the other three on the other question. Or both.

Comment: Thanks, this helped. Is there a way to add the comments at any point in the line tough? For example after a statement

Comment: @Benjer it is the first bullet above: `MOVE A TO B *> This moves a to b`. Personally, as I use meaningful names and particular formatting, I'd never have room for an in-line comment. Also, with the meaningful names, all comments tend to become like my example `This copies the content of a to b`. So don't be worried if, as you become more experienced, you limit comments to essential ones only.